# Is it possible to reset the iOS 100 device limit?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, beta-testing

I'm new to iOS and would like to run 2 beta tests (ad-hoc distribution through the TestFlight app) - one for iPhone and another one for iPad.

There is a limit of 100 devices to register in the iOS Dev Center, will I be able to add 100 new devices for the iPad beta after I delete all the iPhone devices from the first beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you account will only be reset after your subscription will expire.

After you subscription expired and you renewed your account you can delete device.
You will be allowed to remove device until you add a new one.

This is clearly stated in the [Account Management documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html):

> **How many iOS devices can I register for testing and Ad Hoc
>   distribution?**
>
> ---
>
> You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad
>   Hoc distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may
>   remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against
>   your 100 device limit.

Comment: Do I understand right that I only can run a beta with 50 iPhone and 50 iPad user within a year? There is no way to edit UDIDs of testers if they change to a their device? (e.g iPhone 4 to iPhone 5)

Comment: Yes you understand correctly, only a 100 device per year.With device I mean any iPad, iPhone or iPod touch. There is no way to edit/remove/reset this limit within a year.